# Вывод постов через js

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Пишу сайт на php и js. Появилась задача вывод постов из бд через js (ajax) с помощью ленивой загрузки. У меня возникли два варианта:

1. получить абсолютно все записи, а потом уже на клиенте их делить
2. получать также все, но через LIMIT и просто добавлять дальше

Мне кажется первый вариант не оптимизирован, так как постов может быть 100 а то 1.000
Как бы вы поступили?

Comment: Да первый вариант определённо не оптимизирован, а второй не ясен... нельзя получить одновременно ВСЕ записи и использовать LIMIT.  Это протеворечит друг другу

Comment: Использовать LIMIT, OFFSET - частоиспользуемая практика

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду поучать несколько записей через LIMIT. А сама идея вывода через js является адекватной?

Comment: Ну да, например современные инструменты в виде react, vue, angular так и делают